# Android - if I set the Android version to 2.3.3 but left minVersion=4 in the manifest, will the app crash?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I recently changed the properties to have sdk 2.3.3
But I have this in the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Will my app crash for some users if I leave it like this? Or is it ok?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties you talk about are the ones deciding which SDK your application is compiled against. Your application will only crash if use actually use features not supported by older devices that you still declare to support in your manifest

Comment: Some nit picking: Manifest SDK versions are not compile-time restrictions. They are checked at install time.